# Help with binding in WPF

Tags: wpf

```
<Image Source="sourceHere" Stretch="Uniform" Width="100" Height="100">
    <Image.ToolTip>
        <Image Source="{Binding thisImage.Source}" Stretch="Uniform" />
    </Image.ToolTip>
</Image>
```

the parent image is a thumbnail of a bitmap, but I want the tooltip to show the image with 100% size.

How can I bind the image within the tooltip to the parent's source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Image x:Name="thisImage" Source="sourceHere" Stretch="Uniform" Width="100" Height="100">
    <Image.ToolTip>
        <Image Source="{Binding ElementName=thisImage, Path=Source}" Stretch="Uniform" />
    </Image.ToolTip>
</Image>
```

should do it